# nginx conditional pre-render pages for SEO(if + try_files)

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

For SEO purpose, I have a rendering server that will serve fully rendered webpage to googlebot.

`IF 
  UA is googlebot THEN proxy pass to rendering server
ELSE
  serve page normally`

Now the problem is, when I mix `if` and `try_files` together, it never works.

**How can I change the following config to something that works as the above logic?**

```
location ~ ^/web/(.*) {
    if ($http_user_agent ~* "googlebot|bingbot|yandex") {
        proxy_pass http://render.domain.com;
        break;
    }

    try_files $uri /project/$1 /project/dist/$1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two regular expressions in that configuration. When `nginx` encounters a new regular expression, it will reset the numbered captures.

So, whereas you expect `$1` to be the capture from the `location` statement, it is in fact an empty capture from the `if` statement.

You can use named captures instead. For example:

```
location ~ ^/web/(?<name>.*) {
    if (...) { ... }    
    try_files $uri /project/$name /project/dist/$name;
}
```

Comment: This answer, should be in the official document of nginx.  I have spent hours debugging this.  Although I am almost getting to figure it out, your concise answer is the best.